# Python 2.7 prints Unicode as a square box in the Python console

Tags: python, unicode, cjk

I use the latest Python 2 with pycharm on a Mac.

In the Python console, I noticed that if I do `print u'\u31d4'`, the Python console prints out a half square box, ㇔. So does `print u'\u31d2'`. But `31d4` should be a `cjk` stroke, as seen in http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=31d4; and `31d2` should be a different stroke, as in http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=31d2.

Questions:

1. What can I do so that the Python console prints out these strokes correctly?
2. A related question: the Python console currently doesn't print out Unicode characters by default, unless I explicitly call `print`. For example:

   (console prompt)>>> a = u'\u4e00'

   (console prompt)>>> a

The console prints out `u'\u4e00'`.

Only if I explicitly use `print a` would I get `一` back. Can I change a setting somewhere so that it prints `一` in response to typing `a` in the console, without me having to call print?

Comment: does your console running the python console support unicode output? if it does not you'll see the squares as you have pointed out.

Comment: One question per question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Question 2

What is displayed by the interpreter is governed by the function `sys.displayhook`.  Loosely speaking, the default display hook displays the `repr` of the value unless it is `None`.

To alter the `displayhook` simply set to another function. For example:

```
>>> a = u'\u4e00'
u'\u4e00'
>>> import sys
>>> def my_display(x):
...     if isinstance(x, unicode):
...         sys.stdout.write(x.encode("utf-8"))
...     else:
...         sys.stdout.write(repr(x))
...     sys.stdout.write("\n")

>>> sys.displayhook = my_display
>>> a
>>> 一
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at iPython QtConsole, it supports Unicode output very well

Answer (score 1):

Question 1 depends on your IDE's font support.  You get replacement characters if the font doesn't support the character.  Get better fonts and/or a better IDE.

Question 2: That is Python 2's default for the interactive console:  ASCII output with escape codes for non-ASCII.  Python 3 still quotes the string, but prints supporting Unicode characters.  `print` is the correct way to render the string.  You can't change the default.  It is that way for debugging.  Consider:

```
>>> s
u'\xa0\xa0\xa0'
>>> print s

>>>
```

How would you know what the content of `s` was otherwise?  The first way you know it is three Unicode characters, and they are the Unicode codepoint U+00A0, but rendering three non-breaking spaces doesn't tell you much.

Comment: You can "change the default" by altering `sys.displayhook`

Comment: Ok, you can change the default, but don't. You will eliminate a useful debug feature, and if you print something that can't be encoded in the terminal's default encoding, you'll get a UnicodeEncodeError exception.

Comment: Thank you @MarkTolonen! Yes I changed the IDE's font support to "BabelStone Han" as the default. Amazing enough, aside from printing correctly to console, even my webpages outside of the IDE are now rendered correctly. This stackoverflow page now shows the stroke, where I previously copied and pasted what I thought was a square box. I can only accept one answer, so I'll accept @donkopotamus', for his effort in writing the code for altering sys.displayhook. But I agree I should probably not change sys.displayhook -- unless I can change it back. Please keep your answer here, as it's helpful.